# MVC Pagination in both the main and partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination

My app shows two tabulated set of data: the main table with the primary data and a sub-table with related records in a rendered partial view.

For the main table, I have implemented a simple paging functionality. I use `PageInfo` class to store information on actual page, maximum page, number of all pages etc. All this is returned to View in a ViewModel. I also use hidden control and POST form method to send an altered page back to a Controller. 
First I store the current page in a hidden control and then use jQuery to alter the page (+1, -1, frist, l;ast) and send such updated value of a control to the Controller. I struggled to send the page info to the Controller so added a hidden form field and retrieve its value in Action using ModelBinder.

The problem is that I render partial View which is also tabulated data. I would like to apply independent inner page navigation in this subtable. However, I don't know how to use second form if it's possible. It looks like POST method is not the best option.

How can I send separated page information to a partial view. Then how to control whether user clicked inner version of next, previous buttons etc. How can I send this info to controller of the Partial View?

---

EDIT.

In edit, I have added

1. A copy of class representing pagination information
2. Controller with specific actions.
3. View

This is the way I have done it. The first time `Index()` is requested, I set default values for `SortingPagingFilteringInfo` (currently it holds only info on pagination). Everything is put into `ViewModel` and sent to View. I use `Ajax` to replace html in `<div id="listOfRecordings"></div>` with code generated by a partial view and also to navigate around pages. As can be seen, I also use a Form Control in this little code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("page", Model.SPFInfo.CurrentPage)
}
```

to return updated page info. I replace its values in `JavaScript` code below. At the moment it's just a page number. I find it difficult to apply this technique to added pagination to the partial view which also shows tabulated data. They are related to main table by foreign key. It's 1 to many relationship. I tried to add extra `Form` with another `Form Control` to PartialView but then I'd have to have two `Forms`. I don't know how to POST to two different actions / controllers. I haven't played with multi forms in one View. Perhaps there's a better way to solve this.

Pagination model:

```
public class SortingPagingFilteringInfo
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int MaxPage { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageCount { get; set; }
}

public class StudentViewModelWithFeatures
{
    public IEnumerable<StudentViewModel> Students { get; set; }
    public SortingPagingFilteringInfo SPFInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller and GET and POST `Index()` actions:

```
#region Index
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    StudentViewModelWithFeatures ViewModel =
                    new StudentViewModelWithFeatures();
    ViewModel.SPFInfo = new SortingPagingFilteringInfo();
    using (MyDBContext dbContext = new MyDBContext())
    {
        ViewModel.Students = getViewModel(dbContext).OrderBy(x => x.patient);
        ViewModel.SPFInfo.CurrentPage = 1;
        ViewModel.SPFInfo.MaxPage =
                    Convert
                    .ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)getViewModel(dbContext)
                    .Count() / ViewModel.SPFInfo.PageSize));
        int skipRecords =
                    (ViewModel.SPFInfo.CurrentPage - 1) * ViewModel.SPFInfo.PageSize;
        ViewModel.Students = ViewModel.Students
                                .Skip(skipRecords)
                                .Take(ViewModel.SPFInfo.PageSize)
                                .ToList();
    }
    return View(ViewModel);
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult IndexPost(int? page)
{
    StudentViewModelWithFeatures ViewModel = new StudentViewModelWithFeatures();
    ViewModel.SPFInfo = new SortingPagingFilteringInfo();
    using (MyDBContext dbContext = new MyDBContext())
    {
        ViewModel.Students = getViewModel(dbContext).OrderBy(x => x.patient);
        // paging
        ViewModel.SPFInfo.MaxPage =
                    Convert
                    .ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)getViewModel(dbContext)
                    .Count() / GlobalPageSize.Value));
        page = page ?? 1;
        page = page < 1 ? 1 : page;
        page = page > ViewModel.SPFInfo.MaxPage ? ViewModel.SPFInfo.MaxPage : page;
        ViewModel.SPFInfo.CurrentPage = page.Value;
        int skipRecords =
                    (ViewModel.SPFInfo.CurrentPage - 1) * ViewModel.SPFInfo.PageSize;
        ViewModel.Students = ViewModel.Students
                                .Skip(skipRecords)
                                .Take(ViewModel.SPFInfo.PageSize)
                                .ToList();
    }
    return View(ViewModel);
}
#endregion
```

View with JavaScript, `div` for a PartialView:

```
@model Program.ViewModels.StudentViewModelWithFeatures

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Students";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("page", Model.SPFInfo.CurrentPage)
}

<div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <div class="navigation-block">
        <span class="navigation-link" data-id="first"><<<&#160;First&#160;</span>&#160;&#160;&#160;
        <span class="navigation-link" data-id="previous"><&#160;Previous</span>&#160;&#160;
        @Model.SPFInfo.CurrentPage / @Model.SPFInfo.MaxPage
        &#160;&#160;<span class="navigation-link" data-id="next">Next&#160;></span>&#160;&#160;&#160;
        <span class="navigation-link" data-id="last">Last&#160;>>></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listOfRecordings"></div>  <!-- Partial view is placed here -->

<script>
    // for better readability I put this java code below!
</script>
```

JavaScript code in the View

```
$('.navigation-link').click(function (evt) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Students")';
    var MaxPage = "@Model.SPFInfo.MaxPage";
    var CurPage = "@Model.SPFInfo.CurrentPage";
    if (id == 'first') {
        $('#page').val(1);
    }
    if (id == 'last') {
        $('#page').val(parseInt(MaxPage));
    }
    if (id == 'next') {
        $('#page').val(parseInt(CurPage) + 1);
    }
    if (id == 'previous') {
        $('#page').val(parseInt(CurPage) - 1);
    }
    $('form').submit();
});

$('.show-list').click(function () {
    $('.show-list').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        url = '@Url.Action("List", "Recordings")';
        $('#listOfRecordings').html("Retrieveing data ...");
        $.get(url, { StudentID: id }, function (data) {
            $('#listOfRecordings').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you give some examples from your code? Maybe provide something you've tried or thinking would work for your problem?